# Send Date/Time values from options dialog to server component

Tags: c#, scope, datetimepicker

I need to set a date and time (I'm planning to use a DateTimePicker) to set an arbitrary date and time in an Options dialog of a user interface software module. Then I need to pass that to a separate server component, which will use that value as the current date and time and increment time from there normally. The server will also send the date and time into a string variable to a client device through either TCP/IP or RS232.

I suspect that the server code needs to include something along the lines of

```
TimeSpan duration = new TimeSpan();
string futureDay = string.Format("{0:dd}", DateTime.UtcNow.Add(duration));
string futureMonth = string.Format("{0:MM}", DateTime.UtcNow.Add(duration));
```

etc., for all the date/time fields (now that I think of it, I can probably get by with just "date" and "time" fields without breaking them down further).

Being new to programming, I'm uncertain how to pass the values all the way through from the options dialog to the duration object at the server, or whether I should be using a configuration file to store the date and time values and somehow have that config file visible to the server object and use the values from there.

Ultimately, these values will be put into GPS NMEA sentences, and the point of making the time configurable is to test how a device reacts to daylight saving time, for example.

Comment: What is your question exactly? How to pass data to remote party by tcp and store it in a file?

Comment: I suppose the crux of my question is how to set the duration object in the server from values that are defined in a UI-side options dialog.

Comment: You mean you have two date pickers and how to get duration? `picker2.Value - picker1.Value`. This will give you TimeSpan that can be transferred as Ticks, for example.